# Issues center aligning dynamic text element with css

Tags: css, dynamic

I'm trying to center a text element with a dynamic width.

HTML:

```
<div class="healthyrecipes">
<h2>Recipe of the week</h2>
<a href="link"><img src="image" alt="Dip - hommus">
</a>
<span class="recipethisweek">Dip - hommus</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.recipethisweek {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
height: 16px;
left: 30px;
padding: 0 5px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
top: -20px;
vertical-align: text-top;
width: auto;
}
```

The full code is at: http://www.betterhealth.vic.gov.au/

I've tried all sorts of variations according to the similar questions in Stack Overflow but with no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,
Benet

Comment: The text seems to be centered for me, what browser do you use?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you want to make centered h2 element text;

You can use below;

```
<div style="text-align:center;">Recipe of the week</div>
```

instead of

```
<h2>Recipe of the week</h2>
```

You can easily give  effect h2 element with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think he wants to centre the .recipethisweek spanned text.

Don't float it. You already have display block and text-align: center, so that should do it. Also it looks to me like you need to remove the negative top margin as its overlapping the image frame.

Comment: Sorry for being a little unclear, yes I am trying to centre the .recipethisweek spanned text. The negative top margin is incidental to make the text look like a label on the photo.